# How I can plot a variable calculating it since the last bar to bar in the past, bar by bar

Tags: pine-script, return-value, back

I want to calculate the summation of the "relative true range" (close>open? TR : -TR) only on some last bars,
that is from the barstate.islast to, for example, 50/100 bars in the past.

Here below you can see my script:

```
indicator("Σ relative True Range", overlay=false)
barsBack = input(50)
TR_rel = close>=open? TR : -TR
TR_rel=0.0
if barstate.islast
    for i = barsBack-1 to 0 
        SumTR_rel := SumTR_rel + TR_rel[i]
        plot(SumTR_rel, title="Σ relative True Range", color=color.new(color.red, 80), linewidth=2)
```

I tried to do in this way, by inserting a plot in a for cycle, but it happens an error: "cannot use plot in local scope".
I tried to use also line, but I saw that it is usable only in the main panel (overlay=true and not in overlay=false).

Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last bar index using last_bar_index. Then on each bar you can check if the current bar index is within 50 bars of last bar index. Only then you can add the TR to sum and plot the same. Example below

```
    //@version=5

indicator("Σ relative True Range", overlay=false)
barsBack = input(50)
TR=ta.tr(true)
TR_rel = close>=open? TR : -TR
var SumTR_rel=0.0
if bar_index>last_bar_index-barsBack
    SumTR_rel := SumTR_rel + TR_rel
plot(SumTR_rel, title="Σ relative True Range", color=color.new(color.red, 80), linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Dear Rohit Agarwal,
You understood what I need but the script doesn't work well.
I tried to change the target, in order to understand whether the output were right or wrong, by verifying step by step and by using very low barsBack (5-10).
So the new target is Close-Open, instead of True Range.
And so the resulting script with new target should be:

Comment: indicator("Σ close-open", overlay=false)
barsBack = input(50)
CO= close-open
//The calculation of relative in this case it is not needed
//TR_rel = close>=open? TR : -TR
SumCO_rel=0.0
if bar_index>last_bar_index-barsBack
    SumCO := SumCO + CO
plot(SumCO, title="Σ close-open", color=color.new(color.red, 80), linewidth=2)

Comment: What I see with this script structure is:
- when the calculation is done in the last 50th bar, the output is 0
- when the calculation in 49th bar, the output is CO
- when the calculation in 48th bar, the output is also CO because  SumCO is set to zero at every execution of the script, then also in the next bars towards the last.

Is it right what I saw?
How is it possible to remember the SumCO of the previous bar?
I hope I explained myself...

Have a good day!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in StackOverlfow...

Comment: i have edited my answer to not reset sum to 0 on every candle